# Convert image from docker to singularity

Tags: docker, containers, grafana, readonly

I converted grafana docker image to singularity

```
sudo singularity build grafana.simg docker://grafana/grafana
```

But when I try to run it

```
sudo singularity run grafana.simg
```

I get

> EROR[12-02|08:38:53] Server shutdown
> logger=server reason="Service init failed: failed to connect to
> database: failed to create SQLite database file
> "/var/lib/grafana/grafana.db": open /var/lib/grafana/grafana.db:
> read-only file system" Service init failed: failed to connect to
> database: failed to create SQLite database file
> "/var/lib/grafana/grafana.db": open /var/lib/grafana/grafana.db:
> read-only file system

How can i solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Since Singularity images are `read-only` by default you need to specify a [Bind Path](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.7/user-guide/bind_paths_and_mounts.html?highlight=bind%20path#bind-paths-and-mounts).

Try creating a folder on your host for storing Grafana's data.

```
mkdir -p grafana/data
```

After this you should be able to start the container.

```
singularity run --bind grafana/data:/var/lib/grafana grafana.simg
```